# multiple colormaps

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to define multiple colormaps. But when I try this

```
\pgfplotsset{
colormap={something}{
color(0cm)=(blue);
color(1cm)=(orange!75!red)
}
colormap={somethingelse}{
color(0cm)=(white);
color(1cm)=(orange!75!red)
}
}
```

I get an error.
(This works):

```
\pgfplotsset{
colormap={something}{
color(0cm)=(blue);
color(1cm)=(orange!75!red)
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: put a comma in between two declarations

Answer (score 4):

It's a typo since options in the key value syntax needs a separating comma. This would work;

```
\pgfplotsset{
colormap={something}{
color(0cm)=(blue);
color(1cm)=(orange!75!red)
},%<---- comma here
colormap={somethingelse}{
color(0cm)=(white);
color(1cm)=(orange!75!red)
}
}
```